# PHP how to filter multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have a multidimentional array that i want to validate

```
$new = [];
$old = [
        [
        'name'=>'ben',
        'age'=>20,
        ],
        [
        'name'=>'ben',
        'age'=>20,
        ],
        [
        'name'=>'ben',
        'age'=>##,
        ],

]
```

i want to move any sub array that have a value equal to "##" from the $old array  to the $new array, so the result will be like this:

```
$old = [
        [
        'name'=>'ben',
        'age'=>20,
        ],
        [
        'name'=>'ben',
        'age'=>20,
        ],

];
$new = [
            [
            'name'=>'ben',
            'age'=>##,
            ],

    ]
```

i tried filter_arry and in_array without success

Comment: Use foreach and if you find a match, add it to the new array.

Comment: @neodan ‘##’ can be also the value of ‘name’  and there are more elements in the $old array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays.
>   foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when
>   you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an
>   uninitialized variable.
>
> There are two syntaxes:
>
> - `foreach (array_expression as $value)`
> - `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)`
>
> The first form loops over the array given by array_expression. On each iteration, the value of the current element
>   is assigned to $value and the internal array pointer is advanced by
>   one (so on the next iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).
>
> The second form will additionally assign the current element's key to
>   the $key variable on each iteration.

Example:

```
<?php
$new = [];
foreach ($old as $k => $v) {
    if ($v['age'] == '##') {
        $new[] = $v;
        unset($old[$k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the user is new to PHP (obviously) -- I'd explain the key and value meanings in the foreach to make the answer more meaningful.

Comment: @Zak I tried the same code of Neodan but instead of his condition I used in_array(“###”,$v)

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's array_filter function with a callback:

```
$new_arr = array_filter($old, function ($old) {
    return ($old['age'] == '##');
});

$old_arr = array_filter($old, function ($old) {
    return ($old['age'] != '##');
});

print_r($new_arr);
print_r($old_arr);
```

Comment: There is no point to go through whole `$old` array two times.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
$new[] = array();
$old = array(

            array('name'=>'ben','age'=>'20'),
            array('name'=>'ben','age'=>'40'),
            array('name'=>'ben','age'=>'##')


       );


foreach( $old as $array ){

//print_r( $array );
        if( $array['age'] == "##" ){

                $new[] = $array['name'];
                $new[] = $array['age'];

                unset($array['name']);
                unset($array['age']);

        }

        //print_r( $array );
        print_r( $new);
}
```